# Рандомное чтение из файла с помощью pread(2)

Tags: файлы, perl, io

Рандомно считать строки из файла, используя *read(2)* - нельзя. Можно ли использовать для этих целей *pread(2)*, и каким-то образом считывать строки рандомно, учитывая то, что их длина разная?

```
open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
```

Далее код значения не имеет.

Например, *`file.txt`* содержит следующие строки:

```
Gfd65
77
jfgb-fd
system99-st-rws
...
```

Хотелось бы чтобы чтение из файла начиналось не с `Gfd65` а, например, с какой-нибудь другой строки. В общем - рандомно.

Comment: «рандомно» — это «случайно» или «произвольно»?

Comment: Ставите с помощью pos указатель в файле на случайную точку и читаете 2 строки. первую из которых выбрасываете, потому что она возможно не с начала. Если хочется read/pread, считываете блок с запасом и берете строку между первым и вторым переводом каретки